# Why isn't my service running? (As judged by displaying Toast message.)

Tags: android, service, toast

I am trying to make a service in the background so I can run a loop that requests a page every x minutes. This is my service in the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".webToSMS" android:enabled="true" />
```

And here is my service being started (in the main activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, webToSMS.class);
startService(intent);
```

And finally, this is my service class:

```
public class webToSMS extends IntentService {

  public webToSMS() {
      super("webToSMS");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
      int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
      toast.show();
  }
}
```

I was following the guide at Android and this is what it told me to do. What I am expecting is a toast to pop up saying "Hello toast!" when this service is run. Eventually when this works I will put a loop which will request a page every x minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service is running, it's just not displaying the toast because you are not on the UI thread.

If you want to see a toast try this instead

```
Handler HN = new Handler(); 


private class DisplayToast implements Runnable {

  String TM = "";

      public DisplayToast(String toast){
          TM = toast; 
      }

      public void run(){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

   HN.post(new DisplayToast("New Toast on UI Thread")); 
}
```