# Starting a service and auto login from IntentService

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I have the IntentService below that should start MessagingService.class and then automatically login the user to the app and send a notification. At present, upon receiving the GCM message, the notification is sent, but nothin else, not even the Toast messages in the early part of the IntentService appear.

Why would this be the case?

IntentService:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    // Logging stuff:
    protected static final int NOT_CONNECTED_TO_SERVICE = 0;
    protected static final int FILL_BOTH_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD = 1;
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_FAILED = "0";
    public static final String FRIEND_LIST = "FRIEND_LIST";
    protected static final int MAKE_SURE_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_CORRECT = 2;
    protected static final int NOT_CONNECTED_TO_NETWORK = 3;

    private Manager imService;
    public static final int SIGN_UP_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    public static final int EXIT_APP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    // For GCM
    String regid;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    // END logging in


    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Start my service for messages:
        Intent beginMessageService = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MessagingService.class);
        startService(beginMessageService);

        // Try to log in:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Relieved Feast GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // and log in automatically:
        //If not logged in already nad shared preferences exists as already logged in once:
        if (!SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(getApplicationContext()).isEmpty()) {

            //startService(new Intent(this, MessagingService.class));

            final String userName = SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(getApplicationContext());

            final String password = SaveSharedPreference.getPassword(getApplicationContext());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SharedPref Username is " + userName + " and password " + password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The value of imService is: " + getApplicationContext(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (imService == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.not_connected_to_service,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // showDialog(NOT_CONNECTED_TO_SERVICE);
                //return;
            } else if (imService.isNetworkConnected() == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.not_connected_to_network,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // showDialog(NOT_CONNECTED_TO_NETWORK);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SharedPref Username is " + userName + " and password " + password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Thread loginThread = new Thread() {
                    private Handler handler = new Handler();

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String result = null;

                        try {
                            result = imService.authenticateUser(
                                    userName.trim(),
                                    password.trim());
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (result == null
                                || result.equals(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) {
                                      /*
                                       * Authenticatin failed, inform the user
                                       */
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            R.string.make_sure_username_and_password_correct,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    // showDialog(MAKE_SURE_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_CORRECT);
                                }
                            });

                        } else {                                      /*
                                       * if result not equal to authentication failed,
                                       * result is equal to friend and group list of
                                       * the user 0: is for friends, 1: is for groups
                                       */

                        }

                    }
                };
                loginThread.start();

            }


            //setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "
                        + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());

                // Start the background service:


                // Auto log the user in based on store preferences:



            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service won't have access to the UI thread. Consider using `Log` statements instead of a `Toast`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21516064/1832900

Comment: Can you paste your Manifest file? Also make sure you put your GCMIntentService in the main folder..don't put it under any sub folder, and it will work